# Redes Neurais e Inteligência Artificial em PHP?

Tags: php, inteligência-artificial, redes-neurais

Estou interessado em criar softwares inteligentes em PHP, porém não sei por onde começar, <strike>pois há pouco material sobre isso.</strike>

O que redes neurais e inteligência artificial tem em comum ou como trabalham juntas?

Por onde começar a desenvolver sistemas com IA em PHP? Algum exemplo(código) para tomar como ponto de partida?

Comment: Redes Neurais é um sub-tópico de Inteligencia Artificial, existem vários matérias sobre o assunto, livros(em por tugues e em inglês), tutoriais na internet e etc, porém é muito vasto.... apesar de achar interessante o assunto acredito que essa pergunta é muito ampla.... Positivei a questão pois gosto do assunto, e acharia interessante se alguém se disponibilizasse a escrever um textão aqui rs, mas acho difícil...

Comment: Eu começaria procurando livros sobre o assunto, e depois frameworks em php, pra IA deves ter em mente arvore e métodos de busca em arvore, encontrar a melhor solução de um problema usando algum critério "inteligente", redes neurais é o contrario, o algoritmo "aprende" depois de um criterioso ensinamento por meio de centenas, senão milhares de iterações o melhor caminho de uma solução

Comment: Mais uma coisa...... já pensou em JS? Pra desenvolver uma rede neural, eu ACHO(com um enorme acho nisso) que PHP é muito robusto... um JavaScript no lado do servidor, usando Node.js poderia ser mais eficiente e intuitivo, existem ferramentas muito boas pra criação de uma RNA(ver http://synaptic.juancazala.com/#/), porém com PHP não é impossível, mas não seria a MINHA primeira escolha.

Comment: Olá. Como já comentaram, o assunto é bem vasto, de modo que uma resposta que cobrisse bem o que vc quer seria excessivamente longa. Procure estudar um pouco mais do assunto, e volte aqui com questões mais objetivas que você será sempre bem vindo. :) De todas as formas, na prática você pode implementar uma RNE em qualquer linguagem, mas é necessário verificar se isso é interessante ou não (por exemplo, alguém sugeriu utilizar JS, o que talvez não seja o ideal porque o mais computacionalmente custoso é o treinamento da rede, não sua execução).

Comment: Sobre o que esses conceitos têm em comum, leia mais aqui mesmo, nas outras perguntas na tag [tag:inteligência-artificial]. Finalmente, sobre por onde começar, eu te sugiro estudar a tecnologia antes de focar na implementação. Se você entender bem como as RNEs funcionam, você mesmo consegue implementar algo em PHP. Só então, procure algo já pronto. Se PHP não for mesmo um requisito, eu sugeriria utilizar Python com a fantástica biblioteca [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/) (que tem muuuiiiitttaaa coisa pronta).

Comment: Realmente sei que a pergunta é meio ampla, mas corri o risco de ser negativada ou fechada, pois é melhor saber diretamente das pessoas que já sabem sobre o assunto do que ler artigos na internet de muitas vezes pessoas que realmente não sabem do assunto. Sobre a escolha do PHP foi porque é aquele linguagem "xodó", mas ja trabalhei com Python, vou dar uma olhada. Vou tentar continuar as buscas sobre material, embora esteja meio difícil.

Answer (score 3):

### Desculpe-me pela formatação, estou um pouco apressado, mas segue umas dicas.

> "Em primeiro lugar motiva-se o paradigma da neurocomputação pelas
>   capacidades cognitivas de redes neurais biológicas, inspirado pelo
>   conhecimento da neurociência. Os fundamentos das RNA são o modelo de
>   um neurônio, a topologia da rede e os paradigmas de aprendizagem. O
>   modelo de McCulloch e Pitts serve como modelo básico de um neurônio
>   artificial.
>
> Redes Neuraus Artificiais são muito úteis em sistemas especialistas,
>   ou seja, em replicar e repetir procedimentos." ¹ (RAUBER, T. W.)

Para início de estudos indico tentar entender um pouco de como o cérebro humano funciona e de como a análise cognitiva funciona. Seria interessante também conhecimento matemático e físico pois muitas equações são complexas.

Uma das linguagens preconcebidas para a IA é o `Prolog` que pode ajudar no que tange a programação predicativa. Segundo o Wikipedia:

> "Prolog é uma linguagem de programação que se enquadra no paradigma de
>   Programação em Lógica Matemática."

***NOTA:*** Lembre-se que Rede Neural é uma arquitetura **especialista!** Aplicá-la em um ambiente com multiplas funcionalidade pode dar trabalho e é indicado o uso da lógica `Fuzzy`.

> "A RNA conta com inúmeros algoritmos para reconhecimento de padrões:
>   Kohonen, Perceptron, Adaline, Backpropagation e muitos outros, cada um
>   com sua especificidade. A principal vantagem em se usar o
>   Backpropagation é que o mesmo trabalha com multicamadas e resolve
>   problemas “não-linearmente separáveis” e alguns algoritmos não
>   resolvem.
>
> Em resumo, um problema “não-linearmente separável” é aquele onde não
>   poderemos separar 2 classes distintas no eixo cartesiano bidimensional
>   apenas traçando uma reta." ² (DEV Media)

Uma forma muito usada da rede neural é a Backpropagation [Backpropagation - DEV Media](http://www.devmedia.com.br/redes-neurais-artificiais-algoritmo-backpropagation/28559)

Segue um link de uma apresentação introdutória encontrada na internet, desculpe-me se você já conhecer o mesmo. 
[Apresentação RNA](http://www.slideshare.net/otaviocx/introduo-s-redes-neurais-com-php-presentation%20%22Apresenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20RNA%22.)

¹-RAUBER, T. W. **Redes neurais artificiais.** Universidade Federal do Espírito Santo, 2005.

² - `http://www.devmedia.com.br/redes-neurais-artificiais-algoritmo-backpropagation/28559` Acessado em 03/06/2016